# Error Running PowerShell Script From Windows form application

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

```
public string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
   Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
   runspace.Open();

   Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
   pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

   pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

   Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

   runspace.Close();

   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (PSObject obj in results)
   {
       stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
   }

   return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

public string LoadScript(string filename)
{
    try
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {

            StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder();

            string curLine;

            while ((curLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                fileContents.Append(curLine + "\n");
            }

            return fileContents.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        string errorText = "The file could not be read:";
        errorText += e.Message + "\n";
        return errorText;
    }
}
```

This is my class library. when first time i press the button my script runs fine but then  again pressed it raise the exception:

> Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it.

If i deleted the folder Logs which is created during script execution then again it works fine.

My script:

```
rmdir D:\Logs
mkdir D:\Logs
Get-EventLog Application |Format-List | Out-File D:\Logs\app.txt
Get-EventLog System |Format-List | Out-File D:\Logs\app.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rmdir` needs you to confirm before deleting the folder if the folder is not empty (you need to type 'Y' and then Enter). And that is why you get an exception because user interaction is not supported.

Use the `Remove-Item` command with `-Recurse -Force` parameters can silently remove the directory. Try to use the following commands instead of rmdir/mkdir.

```
Remove-Item D:\Logs -Recurse -Force
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path D:\Logs
```

Comment: Thank you so much..  It works for me but it take too much time to generate the  result .is there any way to generate faster result?

Comment: I am afraid it has to be that long, one my machine the file is about 60M, there are a lot of entries in the event log

Comment: so  there is no way to faster the solution? and if i want to read i file from location given by user then what should i do?

Comment: First you can do this on a background thread so UI can remain responsive. But I don't know how to make it faster... Maybe if you only need a portion of the event log (like from a certain application), you can use different parameters so Get-EventLog only exports the entries you need, thus making it faster

Comment: Hey When I added Write -host method  to script it show me the same error.IS there any other way to show to user that which line of script is executed?